# How can I get the width and the height of a JavaFX Label?

Tags: java, javafx, resize, label

There are obviously the two methods `getWidth` and `getHeight` but they return the old label size if we just changed the `Label` text value.

For example, in this code, the background is not correctly resized:

```
Label speedLabel = new Label();
Rectangle backgroundLabel = new Rectangle();

// Some initialization

// Change the label text
speedLabel.setText(connection.getSpeed_bps()); // Sets a bigger number

// Adjust the background
backgroundLabel.setWidth(speedLabel.getWidth());
backgroundLabel.setHeight(speedLabel.getHeight());
```

After the initialization, my `Label` is like that:

[image]

And after the text change and the background adjustment, my `Label` is like that:

[image]

I had a look at this post but it recommends a deprecated method:

[How to get label.getWidth() in javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074024/how-to-get-label-getwidth-in-javafx)

Comment: You could bind the **backgroundLabel width & height** to the **speedLabel width & height** e.g.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the pixel width of a String in JavaFX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015698/how-to-calculate-the-pixel-width-of-a-string-in-javafx) (Also [Get the height of a node in JavaFX (generate a layout pass)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152642/get-the-height-of-a-node-in-javafx-generate-a-layout-pass))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for returning the "old" size that the label actually doesn't get updated on the GUI in the moment when you set the `textProperty` of it, therefore the size is not changed.

You can listen to the [widthProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#widthProperty--) and [heightProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#heightProperty--) of the `Label` and resize the `Rectangle` in the listener:

```
speedLabel.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    backgroundLabel.setWidth(newVal.doubleValue());
});

speedLabel.heightProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    backgroundLabel.setHeight(newVal.doubleValue());
});
```

or simply use bindings between the properties:

```
backgroundLabel.heightProperty().bind(speedLabel.heightProperty());
backgroundLabel.widthProperty().bind(speedLabel.widthProperty());
```

But if you just want to achieve a `Label` with some background, you don't actually need a `Rectangle`, just some CSS - you can check this question: [FXML StackPane doesn't align children correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37496348/fxml-stackpane-doesnt-align-children-correctly/37500161#37500161)

Comment: "There is no setWidth method for a Label" -> Sorry, I forgot some code declarations.

Your solution works good, thanks:
`backgroundLabel.widthProperty().bind(speedLabel.widthProperty());`
`backgroundLabel.heightProperty().bind(speedLabel.heightProperty());`
But can I add a margin at the label width?

Comment: I was just assuming that the other control is a `Label` also because of its name. Now with the update I can see its a `Rectangle` -> answer is updated. About the margin: Now as your question is updated, I can see what you want to achieve. Please see the end of the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways.

**Approach 1:**
Give the background color of your label as that of rectangle. So that whatever is the `Label's` size, your background rectangle will take the width accordingly.

```
label.setStyle("-fx-background-color:grey; -fx-padding:5");
```

**Approach 2:**
Bind the Rectangle's size according to your label size

```
rectangle.prefWidthProperty(label.widthProperty());
rectangle.prefHeightProperty(label.heightProperty());
```